# I can't disable Prometheus port 9090 (default) after set up a reverse proxy in Nginx

Tags: prometheus

I had configured a reverse proxy (Nginx) with basic authentication in another port (19090) but i want to disable the default port 9090 because there is not authentication 
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your Prometheus server listen on the local interface only by using the `--web.listen-address="127.0.0.1:9090"` command line flag.
In that way, the server is only accessible via nginx from the outside.

This requires nginx to run on the same host as your Prometheus server.

If your nginx instance runs on a different host, then Prometheus needs to listen on the `0.0.0.0` interface and you should look into using e.g. a firewall like UFW or similar.

Comment: I notice, that record with quotes not work in systemd service unit. I had to write it without quotes: ExecStart=/opt/prometheus/prometheus --web.listen-address=127.0.0.1:9090 ...